# How to decide which of two distributions a sample is from?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, random-variable

I have two random distributions. How can I get a quantitative estimate of the likelyhood that a particular sample was taken from one or the other of the distributions?

To be more precise:

Let $I = [a,b] \subseteq \Bbb R$, and let $S \subset I: \left| S \right| = c \in \Bbb Z$. Let $A$ be a random distribution supported over $I$ with probability density function $f(x)$, and let $B$ be a distribution supported over $S$, with a probability mass function $g(x): g(x) = 0 \vee g(x) \propto f(x)$.

For example, $A$ might be something like this:

[image: PDF of A (Actually a graph of $f(x) = \cosh(x)^{-\frac{1}{4}} \sqrt{25 - x^2}$)]

And then $B$ could be:

[image: PMF of B]

Let $C$ be a normal distribution with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma$ given. Let $A^\prime = A + C$, and $B^\prime = B + C$. Let $P$ be the proposition that some value $x$ was drawn from $A^\prime$, and $Q$ the proposition that $x$ was drawn from $B^\prime$, and let it be given that $P \vee Q$.

Given the values of $I$, $S$, and $\sigma$, and a collection of samples from $A^\prime$, how can I find the highest confidence value at which I can conclude $P$, and the same for $Q$?

Also, what is a computationally efficient way to perform this analysis in the case where $S$ is defined by some type of one-way function, such that enumerating the set is infeasable but membership tests can be performed (Or, formally, given a random oracle $\rho: I \to \{1, 0\}$, then $S$ is defined as $S = \{x:\rho(x)\}$.)

How can I solve this, or what resources are there that have useful information about how to do things like this?

Comment: Also, if anyone knows a more commonly-used notation for any of the terms here, I would appreciate any edits. All the statistics I know is what I learned myself in the past few weeks on the internet, so I don't really know what the standard notation for most statistical things is.

Comment: In the event you can find the likelihoods of the observations under models A' and B', a common test to compare the models is a [likelihood ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test).